# Unwanted space caused by custom jQuery Validation Error Label

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation custom error placement inside of a div at the bottom of each input/select, but by adding the label with the custom error it has created a white space.

**Custom jQuery Label Error:**

```
<label for="autocomplete" class="text-left p-0 m-0 error text-danger" generated="true"></label>
```

[image]

I can make the white space disappear with **CSS:**

```
label.error {
   display: none!important;
}
```

But then the custom errors don't appear when the form is validated.

**Does anyone know how to make the custom jQuery errors appear only when they're validated, maybe display:none by default?**

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/9jLcg1mh/)

I'm open to any CSS3 or JQuery Hacks that can make this work, I've been stuck for the past few day trying to solve this.

**Thanks!**

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('lettersonly', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z," " áãâäàéêëèíîïìóõôöòúûüùçñ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters and spaces only please");

$(".signupForm1").validate ({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;
}, 

    rules: {
            autocomplete:{
           required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 30,
                lettersonly: true
           },

           state:{
           required: true},

        email2: {email:true, required:true}
      },

        messages: {
            email2: {
                required: "Enter your email address",
                },   
                  state: {
                required: "Enter your state"},
            autocomplete: {
                required: "Enter your city",
                minlength: "Too short for a city name",
                maxlength: "Too long for a city name",
                lettersonly: "Only use letters and spaces"

                }, 

                highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    }    
        }

    });
```

**HTML**

```
        <form id="signupform" class="mt-4 p-sm-3 p-2 signupForm1 input-group mb-sm-3 rounded" method="post" action="#">

    <div class=" form-row w-100">

    <div class="input-group col-sm-8 col-12 w-100 ">
       <label style="" class=" w-100">
      <input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete" class="lightfield form-control sentence rounded" placeholder="City"/> <div style=""class="ml-1">  <label for="autocomplete" class="text-left p-0 m-0 error text-danger" generated="true"></label>      </div>

     </label>
    </div>



           <div class="input-group w-100 col-sm-4 col-12 px-1"> 
            <label class=" w-100">

      <select id="inputState" name="state" class="state lightfield form-control sentence rounded">
        <option value="" selected>State</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
      </select>

<div style=""class="ml-1">  <label for="inputState" class="text-left p-0 m-0 error text-danger" generated="true"></label>      </div>



     </label>
    </div>

               <div class="input-group w-100 px-1"> 
            <label class=" w-100">
                <label for="email2" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
                <input style ="" id="email2" type="email" name="email2" class="rounded anchor sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="Email Address"/>        
                <div style="" class="ml-1">  <label for="email2" class="p-0 m-0 error text-danger" generated="true"></label>  
                </div>
        </label>



<button style="" id="enter" name="signup" type="submit" class="bg-success rounded text-uppercase font-weight-bold w-100 mb-2 ctabutton sentence text-white btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Sign up</button>   


       </div>


          </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question and not sure if this would work, but you could try it.

Add an `invalidHandler` to the validate function that sets the display property to `block`. Then set the default to `none`. For example:

```css
label.error {
   display: none;
}
```

```
$(".signupForm1").validate ({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;
}, 
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    $(document).find('label.error').css('display', 'block !important');
},
  ...
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks for the solution. I was thinking about a more complex solution using if else, but I didn't have the expertise to figure it out. Cheers!